# Copy Range and Paste Into Another Range Based on User Input

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am VERY new to VBA so I am sorry if my code is crazy/the logic is more complex than it needs to be. I would appreciate any help I can get with this. I am trying to write a program that essentially will work like so:

**Image temporarily removed due to link quantity constraints

I have a table that contains 10 unit values (with a number assigned to them as a reference - like a code). Each unit corresponds to it's own worksheet that contains two tables referred to as "in" and "out". On the same table as the unit values and corresponding number there is a table where you can type in which unit follows which using the unit numbers. What I want to do is copy the "out" table from the appropriate unit's sheet and paste it into the indicated following unit's "in" table on it's respective sheet.

I have tried to write a program for this - and I do not have any errors when I run it, but nothing happens. Help please!

```
Sub Reporting_Tails()
'Step 1:


Dim oreassay As Range
Set oreassay = Sheets("Ore").Range("B13:K13")
Dim cr1_in As Range
Set cr1_in = Sheets("Crusher 1").Range("B13:K13")
Dim cr2_in As Range
Set cr2_in = Sheets("Crusher 2").Range("B13:K13")
Dim bami_in As Range
Set bami_in = Sheets("Ball Mill").Range("B13:K13")
Dim romi_in As Range
Set romi_in = Sheets("Rod Mill").Range("B13:K13")
Dim cla_in As Range
Set cla_in = Sheets("Classifier").Range("B13:K13")
Dim ro_in As Range
Set ro_in = Sheets("Rougher").Range("B13:K13")
Dim cle_in As Range
Set cle_in = Sheets("Cleaner").Range("B13:K13")
Dim fi1_in As Range
Set fi1_in = Sheets("Filter 1").Range("B13:K13")
Dim fi2_in As Range
Set fi2_in = Sheets("Filter 2").Range("B13:K13")

Dim Tab_in(0 To 9) As Variant
Tab_in(0) = oreassay
Tab_in(1) = cr1_in
Tab_in(2) = cr2_in
Tab_in(3) = bami_in
Tab_in(4) = romi_in
Tab_in(5) = cla_in
Tab_in(6) = ro_in
Tab_in(7) = cle_in
Tab_in(8) = fi1_in
Tab_in(9) = fi2_in
'Step 2:

Dim cr1_out As Range
Set cr1_out = Sheets("Crusher 1").Range("B13:K13")
Dim cr2_out As Range
Set cr2_out = Sheets("Crusher 2").Range("B13:K13")
Dim bami_out As Range
Set bami_out = Sheets("Ball Mill").Range("B13:K13")
Dim romi_out As Range
Set romi_out = Sheets("Rod Mill").Range("B13:K13")
Dim cla_out As Range
Set cla_out = Sheets("Classifier").Range("B13:K13")
Dim ro_out As Range
Set ro_out = Sheets("Rougher").Range("B13:K13")
Dim cle_out As Range
Set cle_out = Sheets("Cleaner").Range("B13:K13")
Dim fi1_out As Range
Set fi1_out = Sheets("Filter 1").Range("B13:K13")
Dim fi2_out As Range
Set fi2_out = Sheets("Filter 2").Range("B13:K13")

Dim Tab_out(1 To 9) As Variant

Tab_out(1) = cr1_out
Tab_out(2) = cr2_out
Tab_out(3) = bami_out
Tab_out(4) = romi_out
Tab_out(5) = cla_out
Tab_out(6) = ro_out
Tab_out(7) = cle_out
Tab_out(8) = fi1_out
Tab_out(9) = fi2_out

'Step 3:

Dim Tab_report As Variant
Set Tab_report = Sheets("Crusher 1").Range("B13:K13")

'Step 4: set value in reporting table to variable
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
Tab_report(i).Value = x
'Step 5: command the in table for i to copy and paste into the assigned out table range.
If x > 0 Then
'Tab_in(i).Copy ([Tab_out(x)])
Tab_in(i).Select
Selection.Copy
Tab_out(x).Select
Selection.Paste


End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Here are some examples from the file I am working with to give a better explanation.

Here is the input (notice I put a 2 in the reporting column for Ore because I want to paste the "out" table values into the crusher 1 "in" table. there are blanks where I do not want the table pasted anywhere: 
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSdMx.png)

Here is examples of the ore and crusher tabs. I hope this helps you understand what I am trying to accomplish!
[ore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da2gj.png)

Comment: So, no pasting is done? What if you change that part to `If x > 0 Then Tab_in(i).Copy Tab_out(x)
End If`?  What happens when you get to that part by walking through it with `F8`? Does it not do anything, or does it run the code, you just don't see anything updating?

Comment: Yes - no pasting. When I debug it stops at me at step 1 were I am defining the ranges and says run-time error 9 - subscript out of range. Do you know how I would fix this issue? Same results with changing the copy statement as well.

Comment: `Set Tab_in(0) = oreassay` (etc etc) if you want to store a reference to the actual Range (and not its value) in the array

Comment: Which line? Literally the first `Set`? Also, you do have sheets named as such right? Edit: OOoh I think @Tim is on it.

Comment: This seems like a super-long way to do something which is pretty simple (though I'm not quite following the last part...)

Comment: I think the error comes from trying to index into `Tab_out(10)` but you defined `Tab-out` as `Dim Tab_out(1 To 9)`.  The reason it's trying to go into `Tab_out(10)` is because of your loop `For i = 1 To 10`.  Because `Tab_out` doesn't have a 10 index, you are getting the "Subscript out of range" error.

Comment: You use `B13:K13` for both the "in" *and* "out" ranges ?

Comment: Yes it stops at the first 'Set'. I do have the sheets named as presented in the code so I don't think that is a problem. @Tim - I hope this doesn't seem silly, but I want to make sure I follow. Right now - I am defining the ranges as variables and then making a range of those variables. Is that logic correct? I tried to add the parentheses and numbers as you suggested but I get the same error as earlier.  'Set oreassay = Sheets("Ore").Range("B13:K13")'

Comment: @ksum Can you provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you for pointing out the mistake in range reference. I must have missed it because the "out" is supposed to be row 18 instead of 13. Also good catch on the index inconsistency, tigeravatar . I will be sure to fix. Also - I realize that this is a long way around a simple task but I'm not very experienced with coding so this was the only way for me to wrap my head around it. If you have any suggestions they are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but something like this should work:

```
Sub Tester()
    'In and Out range addresses
    Const RNG_IN As String = "B13:K13"
    Const RNG_OUT As String = "B18:K18" 'for example

    Dim rw As Range, tbl As Range, v, f As Range
    Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range 'EDIT: added

    'the "control table" (code/unit/reports to)
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C11") 'for example

    'loop over each row in the control table
    For Each rw In tbl.Rows

        'is there a value for "Reports to" ?
        v = rw.Cells(3).Value
        If v <> "" Then
            'If Yes, find the matching sheet
            Set f = tbl.Columns(1).Find(What:=v, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                'got a match, so copy OUT >> IN
                With ThisWorkbook
                   'EDIT
                   Set rngCopy = .Sheets(rw.Cells(2).Value).Range(RNG_OUT)
                   Set rngPaste = .Sheets(f.Offset(0, 1).Value).Range (RNG_IN)
                   rngCopy.Copy rngPaste

                End With
            End If
        End If

    Next rw

End Sub
```

**Note:** this will not clear previously-pasted data from the "In" tables if you remove a "reports to" from your control table.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added some additional information at the end of my original post. Does that make the objective more clear? Would the code you provided still be recommended? I'll have to look up a lot of the syntax because I'm not familiar enough with some of it to follow at this point.

Comment: I have tried the code that you posted and it seems to be hung up on the following line:
`Set tbl = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C11") 'for example'`
I get a 424 run time error where hovering over the error says that tbl = nothing.

Any idea on how I can fix this? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: That's a pretty simple range assignment - should work fine.  I can't tell what the issue might be

Comment: The code actually works just fine now except that it is hung up on the pasting. I see that it selects the correct range - but it errors before it pastes. The highlighted line is `.Sheets(rw.Cells(2).Value).Range(RNG_OUT).Copy _
                         .Sheets(f.Offset(0, 1).Value).Range (RNG_IN)` and the error is '424' Object Required.

Comment: See my edit above - that should help figure out the problem

Comment: Still doesn't work though... It is saying that I have a Next without a For Loop...which is confusing because I see only one For statement and one Next.

** Nevermind. Stupid me. I accidently deleted one of the End If statements.

Looks like I am getting the same paste problem as before.

Comment: Error is on which line?  It's possible one of the sheet names doesn't match an existing worksheet.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Thank you for all of your help! It is working just fine now.